# Are there mouflons without horns?

Tags: animal-identification, spain

Once we were out hiking, we saw a goat-like animal in the hills around Tàrbena (Alicante, Spain). I wasn't sure what it was, cause it didn't have any horn but my mate insisted on a [mouflon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouflon). I didn't know that there were mouflons without any. Indeed, it completely looked like one except of that missing detail on its head.

Was it a mouflon and if yes, in which cases do they not have horn?

Comment: Can you please add your location for questions like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouflon):

> The horns of mature rams are curved in almost one full revolution (up to 85 cm).

You could have seen a young one or a female. Females can be horned or [polled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polled_livestock).